# Ruby on Rails variables and JavaScript-files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a posibility to change variables via Ruby on Rails in a JavaScript-file.

Thats what i do:

page.js.erb

```
var page = {
  settings: {
    locale: '<%= I18n.locale %>'
  }
}
```

If the locale changes (by swichting from page.com/de/ to page.com/en/) the JavaScript does not change the value of page.settings.locale . How to fix this?

Only by editing that file the value is changed. So I think that is a kind of server-side-caching.

Comment: you can't do this.  assets are precompiled in production and will not be recompiled after you tell the server to.  the easiest way to achieve what you want is to create a global namespace for your project and save the variable values there like `MyApp = {}; MyApp.locale = 'en';`